# conversion between Endnote and jabref

Tags: jabref, endnotes

When I want to export Endnote to `.txt` file as `.bib`, and then importing to Jabref, there are many references that are in `misc` mode and `empty`. But in Endnote all of them are OK.
Why?

Comment: I don't think this site is meant to cover answers about any and all software that may export to some TeX-related format. Isn't there a forum or support site devoted to Endnote? (My guess as to the answer to your question is: because Endnote probably doesn't care much about exporting things to the BibTeX format. Perhaps they think no one really wants or needs it --- in which case, it would be wise to let them know that their paying customers do care about such things.)

Comment: This seems to be an EndNote question, which as noted is off-topic for us (sorry).

Comment: I think it is because of jabref software. The .txt that exported via Endnote is complete but when i import to Jabref it is empty

Comment: I don't understand your question: why do you need an intermediate .txt file ? JabRef allows for direct import of EndNote bases (Never try it myseelf since I don't use EndNote), did you tried it ?

Comment: I have a library and group in Endnote. How can i convert it to bib and using in latex?i tried exporting into .txt format anf impoting via Jabref. what is your solution?

Comment: I suggest (again) that you try to import directly from JabRef: File > Import in a new base or Import in an existing base where you can select (via a Filter) the format of the file you want to import, there is a Refer/EndNote filter.

Comment: I did this but there are some empty records

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use this filter: http://endnote.com/downloads/style/bibtex-export-using-en-label-field